# UITableView when click button and change its image Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a problem when I click a button in `UITableView`.

When I click a button to change its image, another indexpath changes it image.

Two buttons change their image when I click one button.

This video is shown the problem :

[Video Shown Problem](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JcNCAx7WpjQNCuwz-i5knbHM-NqR9N2P)

This is my code to button click :

```
  @objc func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let section = 0
    let row = sender.tag
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)


    //let point = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: servicestable as UIView)
   // let indexPath: IndexPath! = servicestable.indexPathForRow(at: point)
    let cell: ServicesCell = self.servicestable.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ServicesCell

        print(sender.tag)


    if  services[indexPath.row].choose == "0" {

        cell.check.setImage(UIImage(named: "Rectangle1"), for: .normal)

        services[indexPath.row].choose = "1"
      //  checkchoose.updateValue(1, forKey: indexPath.row)

        print("number: " + String(indexPath.row))

        chooseservicesw.updateValue("0", forKey: String(indexPath.row+1))


   //     servicestable.reloadData()

    }

  else  if services[indexPath.row].choose == "1" {

        cell.check.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox1"), for: .normal)



        services[indexPath.row].choose = "0"
      //  checkchoose.updateValue(0, forKey: indexPath.row)

        print("number: " + String(indexPath.row))

        chooseservicesw.removeValue(forKey: String(indexPath.row+1))


     //   servicestable.reloadData()

    } }
```

and this is my code to Cell:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell:ServicesCell = servicestable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "servicess", for: indexPath) as! ServicesCell




    cell.name.text = services[indexPath.row].name

    let photo = services[indexPath.row].icon

    let imgURL = MainUrl + photo! // or jpg
  //  cell.icon.setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl: imgURL)

    let url = URL(string: imgURL)
    cell.icon.kf.setImage(with: url)

 //   print(checkchoose[indexPath.row])

    print(services[indexPath.row].choose)



    cell.check.tag = indexPath.row


    cell.check.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.checkpay.tag = indexPath.row


    cell.checkpay.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnAction2(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.price.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.endedit(_:)), for: .editingDidEnd)
    cell.price.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.endedit(_:)), for: .editingChanged)



    cell.selectionStyle = .none



    return cell


}
```

Comment: how many section you have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you perform dequeueReusableCell, iOS not generates your array's counts of cells. Instead of this, it generates fewer cells and use these cells again and again on scrolls. In your case selected shown cells are actually same cells.

**The solution:**  You should store the selection flag for your cells in your datasource array (in your case its *services*). And in *cellForRowAt* method you should select or deselect checkboxes according to your stored selection data.

**Edit:**

```
if  services[indexPath.row].choose == "0" {
    cell.check.setImage(UIImage(named: "Rectangle1"), for: .normal)
    services[indexPath.row].choose = "1"
    chooseservicesw.updateValue("0", forKey: String(indexPath.row+1))
} else  if services[indexPath.row].choose == "1" {
    cell.check.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox1"), for: .normal)
    services[indexPath.row].choose = "0"
    chooseservicesw.removeValue(forKey: String(indexPath.row+1))
}
```

Add this part to end of your cellForRowAt method.

Comment: thanks bro ,, can you write the edited code ? bacouse i am not expert in swift and i am not understand all your comment

Comment: its Works , Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because reuseable cell in Memory you can handle like that:

In Your ViewController or TableViewController add Array that handel selected Model `selectedIndexPathServices` Add your  `YourServiceModel`

Example

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var selectedIndexPathServices :[YourServiceModel] = [YourServiceModel]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   }
}
```

**At your btnAction**

```
  @objc func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let cell = sender.superview?.superview as? ServicesCell else { return}

        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)

        if selectedIndexPathServices.contains(services[indexPath.row]){
            selectedIndexPathServices.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        }else{
            selectedIndexPathServices.append(services[indexPath.row])
        }
    }
```

At your cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:ServicesCell = servicestable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "servicess", for: indexPath) as! ServicesCell


        cell.name.text = services[indexPath.row].name

        let photo = services[indexPath.row].icon

        let imgURL = MainUrl + photo! // or jpg
        //  cell.icon.setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl: imgURL)

        let url = URL(string: imgURL)
        cell.icon.kf.setImage(with: url)

        //   print(checkchoose[indexPath.row])



        if selectedIndexPathServices.contains(services[indexPath.row]){


            if  services[indexPath.row].choose == "0" {
                cell.check.setImage(UIImage(named: "Rectangle1"), for: .normal)
                services[indexPath.row].choose = "1"
                chooseservicesw.updateValue("0", forKey: String(indexPath.row+1))

            }

            else  if services[indexPath.row].choose == "1" {
                cell.check.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox1"), for: .normal)
                services[indexPath.row].choose = "0"
                chooseservicesw.removeValue(forKey: String(indexPath.row+1))
            }

        }

        cell.check.tag = indexPath.row


        cell.check.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        cell.checkpay.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.checkpay.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnAction2(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.price.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.endedit(_:)), for: .editingDidEnd)
        cell.price.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.endedit(_:)), for: .editingChanged)



        cell.selectionStyle = .none



        return cell


    }
```